# SQL SUBQUERY ON SELF

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following data:

```
licence_number
date_of_birth
organisation
```

I want to do a query where:

> Get the licence_numbers and dobs in organisation1 where the same
>   licence numbers and dobs are in organisation2.

I know it cant be that hard, but im struggling.

Comment: Struggling?  Please show the results of your struggles.

Comment: This really is a bad sign of questions showing no effort from the OP being answered by high-rep users without even conforming if the OP has put any effort into it. See here itself : 2 answers by users whose combined rep is greater than **100k**.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny Well, not saying it's a good question, but the "must display a minimal understanding" close reason is gone, and the problem is as far as I can see clearly stated. If you can see a suitable close reason, feel free to vote for close.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The point here is not about "minimal understanding". Its about helping & guiding people in the area in which they are struggling. The question contains no sign of effort and is more of a "give me the code plz" kind of question. That IS the problem here!!

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson And by the way, merely stating "I am struggling" cannot be considered as 'real effort' if that's what you think.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, the question is *'clearly stated'*. But then, *'I want an application developed in `PHP` having `MySQL` as backend providing real-time hourly updates of foreign exchange during business times'* is also **clearly stated.** So, do you think even that should be a possible question here?

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny If you think the question is of bad quality, and I think you are correct if that is the case, then downvote it as I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by license_number and date_of_birth where organization is set to either of the two interesting organizations, and count how many distinct organizations there are in a group.

If there are two out of two possible in a single group, you have a hit.

```
SELECT license_number, date_of_birth
FROM mytable
WHERE organisation IN ('organisation1', 'organisation2')
GROUP BY license_number, date_of_birth
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT organisation) = 2;
```

...or you can use `INTERSECT`;

```
SELECT license_number, date_of_birth
FROM mytable WHERE organisation = 'organisation1'
INTERSECT
SELECT license_number, date_of_birth
FROM mytable WHERE organisation = 'organisation2'
```

[An SQLfiddle to test both](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a25f6/1).

Comment: What makes you believe there are two tables? And you get the same organization from both. What is the point?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Thanks, you're absolutely correct. I updated the answer to answer the correct thing :)

Comment: Thank you, intersect - is what i needed. I was trying to do joins for some reason. Completely forgot about intersect.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
from t t0
where
    organization = 'organization1'
    and
    exists (
        select 1
        from t
        where
            organization = 'organization2'
            and
            licence_number = t0.licence_number
            and
            date_of_birth = t0.date_of_birth
    )
```

Comment: @joop Probably because the downvoter didn't understand neither the question nor the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just self join the table where the licence number and the dates are the same but the organisation isn't:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.licence_number, p1.date_of_birth
FROM people p1
INNER JOIN people p2
ON p1.licence_number = p2.licence_number AND
p1.date_of_birth = p2.date_of_birth AND
p1.organisation <> p2.organisation
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47eb08/2)

Answer (score -1):

Is it a JOIN or 1 table?

```
Select 

[licence_number],
[date_of_birth],
[organisation]
From YourTable
Where organisation1 = organisation2

--OR 

Select 

[licence_number],
[date_of_birth],
[organisation]
From YourTable
Where organisation1 IN ('organisation2','organisation3','organisation3')
Order By [licence_number]
```

Comment: That is invalid SQL (for Postgres and any other standard compliant database).

Comment: You are wanting open source then MySQL